# Flow type error when create union type of primitives and array of primitives

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Im trying to create a `Transform` type to accept the possible values for the attribute but I'm getting an error when trying to combine `string` primitives with arrays of those primitives.

```
export type Transform = {
  matrix?: [number],
  rotate?: number | string,
  scale?: number | [number],
  skew?: string | [string],
  translate?: [number | string],
};
```

The error is complaining about the `skew` and `translate` properties saying that are incompatible with `number` in `matrix` but if I remove `matrix` the error continue with the next line.

This is the error:

```
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ packages/utils/types.js:12:20

string [1] is incompatible with number [2].

 [2]  9│   matrix?: [number],
     10│   rotate?: number | string,
     11│   scale?: number | [number],
 [1] 12│   skew?: string | [string],
     13│   translate?: [number | string],
     14│ };
     15│


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ packages/utils/types.js:13:25

string [1] is incompatible with number [2].

 [2]  9│   matrix?: [number],
     10│   rotate?: number | string,
     11│   scale?: number | [number],
     12│   skew?: string | [string],
 [1] 13│   translate?: [number | string],
     14│ };
     15│



Found 2 errors
```

The project is hosted in GitHub and you can check the file using this type in https://github.com/davegomez/silky/tree/master/packages/group

### Update

I started to suspect that the problem might be the way I'm dealing with the validation before working with the code in the parameter but I'm not sure how do I have to refactor it in order to help Flow to understand what is happening.

This is the code using the Type:

```
// @flow
import type { Transform } from './types';

// Will take the transform object and return the correct transform attribute
// value based on the passed object properties
export default function getTransform(transform: Transform = {}) {
  var { matrix, rotate, scale, skew, translate } = transform;
  var join = x => x.join(', ');
  var attrs = [];

  matrix && attrs.push(`matrix(${join(matrix)})`);
  rotate && attrs.push(`rotate(${rotate})`);
  scale &&
    attrs.push(`scale(${typeof scale === 'number' ? scale : join(scale)})`);
  skew && attrs.push(`skew(${typeof skew === 'string' ? skew : join(skew)})`); // This might be the problem
  translate && attrs.push(`translate(${join(translate)})`); // This might be the problem

  return attrs.length ? attrs.join(' ') : null;
}
```

I just can't spot the mistake I'm making and will appreciate any help.

Comment: which version of flow are you using? I cannot replicate these errors on the flow playground at https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcBmB7OBbKBeKAbwCgopsFg4BLADwH4AuKAbSQFdsAjCOAXQA0pKHAzBKEJlA7deUAD5QUVakgDmQsigDGCADaTmMnnAWtjvQcJQBrCAHcpymurMtnqtVbJVkKPRJSbJwmZh7qVgC+ANxAA

Comment: Hello @DaGardner thanks for asking, my Flow version is 0.94.0 and updated the question with a link to the code. You can also see the build failing due to this error https://travis-ci.org/davegomez/silky/jobs/506396795

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issue and is that Flow weren't able to infer the type of the param in the `join` function.

Declaring the param type as `[any]` will solve the issue:

```
...
var join = (xs: [any]): string => xs.join(', ');
...
```